# In Spark job, few tasks are taking very long (stuck) when using Spark SQL group by

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-hdinsight

I have Spark job (on Azure HDInsight) which runs SQL query (standard groupby) and saves result to Parquet & csv format.

This job is taking really long. When I check Spark UI, I see there are two tasks that are stuck.

[image: Spark slow tasks]

I thought this was because of data skew. However, if I check these executors:

[image: Spark stuck executors]

they have similar size of input data, shuffle read and write. So it doesn't seem to be data skew issue. What other reasons could cause some tasks to take very long?

Just to give some idea about what I am running, sample query:

```
SELECT year_month, id, feature,
min(prev_ts) AS timedelta_min,
max(prev_ts) AS timedelta_max,
stddev_pop(prev_ts) AS timedelta_sd,
AVG(prev_ts) AS timedelta_mean,
percentile_approx(prev_ts,0.5) AS timedelta_median,
percentile_approx(prev_ts,0.25) AS timedelta_1st_quartile,
percentile_approx(prev_ts,0.75) AS timedelta_3rd_quartile
FROM table_a 
GROUP BY id, feature, year_month
```

Here `prev_ts` was column created using `LAG` on timestamp column.

Comment: You could log in to the nodes and `jstack` the PIDs of the executor JVMs to see what's holding them back.